# Why can't I use method on relation in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I wanna using method on relation in laravel but show error`[Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getMessage does not exist.]`.

Error was changed to `Call to a member function getMessage() on null` when I rewrite  `{{$item->board2->getMessage()}}` to `{{$item->aaaaaaaa->getMessage()}}` so I think relation was succeed.

I have no Idea what's wrong.

please give me advice.

Board2.php(model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Board2 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'boards2';

    protected $fillable = [
        'person2_id',
        'message'
    ];

    public function person2()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Person2');
    }

    public function getMessage()
    {
       return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Person2(model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person2 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'people2';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function board2()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Board2', 'person2_id');
    }
}
```

View

```
   <ul>
   @foreach($items_p2 as $item)
   <li>
    {{$item->name}}
   </li>
   <li>
    {{$item->board2->getMessage()}}
   </li>
   @endforeach
  </ul>
```

controller

```
・
・
・

    public function show2()
    {
        $items_p2 = Person2::all();

        $data = [
            'items_p2' => $items_p2
        ];

        return view('Review.show2', $data);
    }
```

migration files

```
class CreatePeople2Table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('people2', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBoards2Table extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('boards2', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('person2_id');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first:
in order to get the relation data you should load it first ...

$items_p2 = Person2::with('board2')-> all();

second: in your blade file

> {{$item->board2->getMessage()}}

$item->board2 return a collection not a single board, so you should put it in foreach as well

```
 @foreach($items_p2 as $item)
   <li>
    {{$item->name}}
   </li>
   <li>
 @foreach($item->board2 as $board)
<li>
    {{$item->board2->getMessage()}}
<li>
   @endforeach
   </li>
   @endforeach
  </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! $item->boards is collection so I had to use foreach! I had no idea what error message say collection about. you save me and your answer is easy for understand!

Answer (score 1):

Inside Board2.php(model) file, you have defined the method **getMessage()**, the method is loaded on the instance of the model and not the array of models (in Laravel's case, multiple models are loaded in a collection).

Inside Person2(model) file, you have defined the relation **board2()** which is linked to Board2 model via HasMany Relation. The catch is that HasMany relation, as the name suggests will load collection from the db and not a single instance of the model.

Try changing HasMany to HasOne inside Person2 model, your error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks !! once I was change to HasOne and user message more than 2 was not show. So I keep HasMany and Change the code to like Mithu A Quayiums answer that's save me! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the code you have written, each board2 record is connected to a single instance of person2, but on the other side, each person2 record is connected to a collection/array of board2 (not connected to single board2). This is the point keep in mind. Now let's proceed to next step.

Let's take a look in your view file. The code you wrote in view is

```
<ul>
   @foreach($items_p2 as $item)
   <li>
    {{$item->name}}
   </li>
   <li>
    {{$item->board2->getMessage()}}
   </li>
   @endforeach
 </ul>
```

Here in $item->board2 , the board2 is not a single instance/record/model, rather it is a collection/array of multiple board2 instances/records/models. And each of that record/model will have the method "getmessage()" as you expected. So, the thing you have to do is, iterate through the records/models by making foreach to $item->board2, this way you will have the access to each single board2 record/model, then call the getMessage() method from that record/model. Let's modify the view code like this.

```
<ul>
   @foreach($items_p2 as $item)
   <li>
    {{$item->name}}
   </li>
   <li>

  @foreach( $item->board2 as $board )

    {{$board->getMessage()}}

    //this echo is just to break the line
    echo '<br>';

   @endforeach


   </li>
   @endforeach
 </ul>
```

Hope it will work now. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! This question is for lack of my knowledge about what return relation method. Also you save me!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this location. You write this in `Person2` model

```
public function getMessage(){
   return $this->message;
}
```